# Use Monte Carlo method to simulate consecutive decay in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, monte-carlo

I'm trying to use MATLAB to simulate an atom decay process by using Monte Carlo approach. The process is as follow:

Suppose that atom 1 decay to atom 2, which, in turn, decay to stable atoms of type 3. The decay constants of 1 and 2 are $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$, respectively.

Assume that at $t = 0$, $N_1 = N_0$ and $N_2 = N_3 = 0$.

$\lambda_1=0.0001$, $\lambda_2=0.00005$,
$t_{\rm MAX}$ for the process is $150000\rm s$.

I'm not really familiar with Monte Carlo method, so I have only managed to simulate the single decay process.When it come to consecutive decay I got completely lost.

I attached my script for single decay below. Hope to get help here.

```
N0=input('Enter total number of nuclides: '); %Determine N0
lambda1 = 0.0001; %decays/s
dt = 100; %time step
M = 1500; % total number of time steps
t = 0:dt:(M-1)*dt; %time series
p = lambda1*dt; %probability of having a decay in the time dt

% Define the array that will be populated with the number of atoms at each time step N = zeros(M,1);

N(1) = N0;

for j=2:M % Loop over time
    nd = 0; % number of decays
    for i=1:N(j-1)
        %generate a single random number  
        r = rand();
        %binary value =1 if the condition is True -> Atom has decayed
        rb = r < dt*lambda1; 
        if rb == 1
           nd = nd+1;
        end    
    end
    N(j) = N(j-1)-nd; % number of atoms left at the step 2
end

plot(t, N)
```

Answer (score 1):

The decay of radioisotopes can be described by a set of coupled first order differential equations $$\frac{dN_{i}(t)}{dt} = -\lambda_{i}N_{i}(t) + \sum_{j \neq i}\lambda_{j\to i} N_{j}(t)$$ where $\lambda_{j\to i}$ represents the decay constant associated with the decay of isotope $j$ to isotope $i$, $\lambda_{i}$ is the total decay constant of isotope $i$ and $N_{i}(t)$ is the time-dependent concentration of isotope $i$.

This can be easily written in matrix form $$\frac{d\bar{N}(t)}{dt} = \bar{A}\bar{N}(t)$$ where $\bar{A}$ is typically very sparse. The numerical difficulties associated with this set of coupled differential equations are twofold:

1. The system can be large (in [our](http://www.hindawi.com/journals/stni/2012/545103/) applications we track about 3500 isotopes)
2. The system is very stiff due to the big differences between decay constants (some isotopes decay with half-lives in milliseconds, others in millions of years)

Luckily, there exist solvers than can handle these problems: solvers for stiff sets of ODEs like implicit Runge-Kutta methods ([RADAU](http://www.unige.ch/~hairer/prog/stiff/radau.f)) or methods based on the matrix exponential method ([CRAM](http://lib.tkk.fi/Diss/2013/isbn9789513880002/isbn9789513880002.pdf)). The application of RADAU to this problem is described in [Advanced Method for Calculations of Core Burn-Up, Activation of Structural Materials, and Spallation Products Accumulation in Accelerator-Driven Systems](http://www.hindawi.com/journals/stni/2012/545103/) (note that I'm co-author of this paper).

I see no reason nor advantage to use a Monte Carlo method to solve this problem. Do you intend to model the stochastic nature of radioactive decay? Why?

Comment: Thanks,but I'm not intend to solve practical problem,it's just I've seen this plot from website:http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ConsecutiveExponentialDecay/, and trying to plot it by using matlab.